# Fixing the output of a first and last name

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning to use arrays and I am confused as to how to get my output to list either: the persons first and last name or just their first name at the end where the two salaries are compared. As of now, it uses the first name and last name of one employee as if they were the first names of the 2 separate employees. Also, is there anything wrong with this coding or anything you see that could be improved? Please understand, I am only on week 4 of learning Java.

```
package salesmanweek4;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Big Werd
 */
public class SalesmanWeek4 extends Nameofsalesman {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] stringArray = {"",""};
        double[] doubleArray;
        doubleArray = new double[2];
    // constructor to take keyboard input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //constructor to instantiate employees
    Nameofsalesman compare = new Nameofsalesman();
    // for loop to populate employeeArray
    System.out.print("What is the first name of the employee?:");
    compare.firstName = keyboard.next();
    stringArray[0] = compare.firstName;
    System.out.print ("What is the last name of the employee?");
    compare.lastName = keyboard.next();
    stringArray[0] = compare.lastName;
    System.out.print("What was this employees total annual compensation?:");
    compare.grossPay = keyboard.nextDouble();
    doubleArray[0] = compare.grossPay;
    System.out.print("What is the next employees first name?:");
    compare.firstName = keyboard.next();
    stringArray[1] = compare.firstName;
    System.out.print ("What is the last name of the employee?");
    compare.lastName = keyboard.next();
    stringArray[1] = compare.lastName;        
    System.out.print("What was this employees total annual compensation?:");
    compare.grossPay = keyboard.nextDouble();
    doubleArray[1] = compare.grossPay;
    double difference;
    if (doubleArray[0] > doubleArray[1]){
        difference = doubleArray[0] - doubleArray[1];
        System.out.print( stringArray[0] + " Earned more compensation " + stringArray[1] + ".");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print( stringArray[1] + " will need to make more sales in the amount of " + difference );
    }
    else if ( doubleArray[0] < doubleArray[1]){
        difference = doubleArray[1] - doubleArray[0];
        System.out.println( stringArray[1] + " earned more than " + stringArray[0] + ".");
        System.out.println( stringArray[0] + " will need to make more sales in the amount of " + difference );
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(stringArray[0] + " wow, you both earned the same! " + stringArray[1] + ".");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Empty lines in code can be your friend, especially for making things more easily readable

Comment: Haven't got too far, but usingProperNamingConventions is much appreciated.

Comment: You read in the first name, store it into `stringArray[0]`, get the last name and immediately overwrite what you got for the first name.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - What in particular are you referring to?

Comment: I'm sorry about the spacing, you are right, I will be adding spacing to make things easier to read.

Comment: @Ascalonian, he got most of them, but class names in Java begin with a cap and continue with camel casing, which is [Pascal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) casing. Should be `NameOfSalesman`. Sorry, neglected to see where that came from.

Comment: @BigWerd - I am also confused on why you're using `compare`. You store the value in the object, then just call the getting on that value. Why not just do something like: `stringArray[0] = keyboard.next();`?

Comment: I'm sure it's for assignment reasons, those pesky professors!, but why do you inherit Nameofsalesman anyway? You end up instantiating a separate instance of a Nameofsalesman instead an instance of `Salesmanweek4` which would have the same result. The structure seems a bit weird.

Comment: I am not sure why I thought I needed to use compare, but I replaced with your suggestion and it is working just fine.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I am required to have 2 separate classes, so my other class is called Nameofsalesman

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to point out what you're "saying" with that code - "Salesmanweek4 *is-a* Nameofsalesman". I think you could remove `extends...` and the program would behave the same way.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Ahhh, ok, I get what you are saying, and you are absolutely right...